# Remove entries with the click of a Button in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, userform

I have a pretty straight forward question.

With this code, I create new entries whenever i click a button:

XAML

```xml
<Button Text="Add Ingredient"  Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Code-behind

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddEntry(EntriesStackLayout, "Ingredient " + x.ToString());
    x++;
}

private void AddEntry(StackLayout sl, string name)
{
    Entry entry = new Entry()
    {
        Placeholder = name,
    };
    sl.Children.Add(entry);
}
```

I want to know what could I do to then remove these entries in order. For last to first?

This is what the app looks like:

[image]

Comment: I think that you would be better off using a datagrid and binding to a list of Ingredient objects. That way you can remove any ingredient just buy selecting it and clicking a button bound to the removal action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what could I do to then remove these entries in order.
> For last to first?

For your problem, you can remove the last element one by one in your StackLayout(`EntriesStackLayout`).

Please refer to the following code:

```
    private void Button_Clicked_Remove(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        var element = EntriesStackLayout.Children.LastOrDefault();

        if (element!=null) { 
           EntriesStackLayout.Children.Remove(element);
        }

    }
```

YouPage.xaml

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label Text="EasyChef" TextColor="Black" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10"/>

            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="Simply select ingredients!" FontSize="Title"/>
            <StackLayout x:Name="EntriesStackLayout">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20" RowSpacing="20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Entry Placeholder="Eg. Eggs" x:Name="EntryTag" Grid.Row="0"/>
                   
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button Text="Add Ingredient"  Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

            <Button Text="Relete Ingredient"  Grid.Row="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Remove"/>

            <CheckBox />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

**Note:**

Make sure to add a null judgement, or the app may crash:

```
       if (element!=null) { 
           EntriesStackLayout.Children.Remove(element);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove an element from a layout

```
sl.Children.Remove(element);
```

If you don’t already have a reference to the element

```
var element = sl.Children.LastOrDefault();
```